# Propensity score in time-updated (counting process) Cox regression

Tags: cox-model, propensity-scores

Suppose I aim to examine if treatment A is better than treatment B.
My dataset consists of 10,000 individuals with a total of 100,000 observations. Thus each individual is observed 10 times and his covariates (blood pressure, blood lipids etc) are updated each visit. To provide more robust estimates, I use all observations in the Cox regression, by counting process syntax. I would like to adjust for propensity score as well but the problem is:

(1) Should the propensity score be calculated for each observation (i.e 10 times for each individual)?

(2) Should the propensity score be calculated once (per individual) and then held fixed?

**My second question**

I have read R D'Agostinos review (http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~john/papers/DAgostinoSIM1998.pdf) on use of propensity score but after reading a paper (which investigated differences in treatment A and treatment B on risk of death), where authors stated that their covariance adjustment was done only by stratification with a propensity score; is it not "better" to include the covariates in the Cox regression as well, despite being included in the prop score?

I did not attach a data set because this is a methodological discussion.

Greetings

Comment: When is the decision to assign treatment A or B is made? If at the beginning, then you want to calculate the propensity only based on covariates present at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, decision is made at the beginning. So you suggest i calculate the prop score at inclusion and then hold it fixed throughout observations. Seems logical.